# How to do dump on PostgreSQL?

Tags: windows, postgresql

I need to create a backup of my DB but I'm receiving the Windows error `0xc000007b` and I am using Windows 10, x64.

I tried;

1. uninstall all windos x84 and x64 libraries and reinstall Visual codese C +
2. paste in the folder of pgadmin bin the libraries of 0xc00007b
3. incorporate the Zlib file into the system32 folder

And Nothing...

Comment: Is your OS 32 bit?

Comment: No, 64 bit......